# Is a diamond (♦) part of a moderator's name?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Assuming that [moderators are on-topic](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3478/5323); how are they called up for an aliyah? Is the diamond mentioned?

It's been discussed before [elsewhere on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240327/266359), though with an appalling lack of Jewish sources.

What do Jewish sources have to say about including a diamond (♦) in a moderator's name for aliyos, legal documents, and the like?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: ....though if moderators are on-topic, [it's been discussed by Jewish sources](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240328/266359)....that doesn't count :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Moderators can quit or be ousted. On the other hand, a diamond is forever. Therefore, [the באר היטב](/a/5748) argues, the diamond can't be part of the moderator's name.

But the ארוך השלחן refutes that argument by noting that "a diamond is forever" is a slogan of De Beers whereas on Purim we're supposed to drink De Wines.

Comment: (‮‮[♦ derF -](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1442/) 1+ .oot ,dnomaid a evah I woN .olleH

Answer (score 13):

Your title and body ask two different questions: is the diamond part of the name, and how do we call a moderator up for an aliyah?  Those are not the same question.

When a rabbi is called up for an aliyah we call "*HaRav* Ploni ben Ploni", but "HaRav" is not part of his *name*; it's a *title*.  While it's extremely rare, should Ploni one day stop being a rabbi he'd lose the "HaRav" but his actual *name* wouldn't change.

Moderators are more temporary than rabbis, so *kal v'chomer* the diamond couldn't be part of the name.

As for how to call a mod to the torah, you don't add any words, just stress one syllable more: "ya-a**mod**..." (or, where I daven, possibly "ta-a**mod**...").

Answer (score 4):

When calling the person for an aliyah, the diamond is mentioned only if the person is a Levi, as it says in Shemot 28:18

וְהַטּוּר, הַשֵּׁנִי--נֹפֶךְ סַפִּיר, וְיָהֲלֹם

Meaning:

The second turn (i.e., the 2nd aliyah) is for a carbuncle, sapphire and diamond.